# Cannot remove user from a Slack channel using API

Tags: slack, slack-api

I have used [`channels.invite`](https://api.slack.com/methods/channels.invite) method to add a user to a slack channel. After the user has been added, I have used [`channels.kick`](https://api.slack.com/methods/channels.kick) method to remove the user from the channel. But the slack returns an error:

> restricted_action:     A team preference prevents the authenticated user from kicking.

What could be the reason that I could not remove a user from a channel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define for your workspace which roles can kick users from a channel. The default is admin / owner.

This can be set under Administration / Workspace Settings / Permissions / Channel Management if your user have the necessary rights to change it.

Apparently the user that owns your API token does not have the required role.

See the help article [Remove someone from a channel](https://get.slack.help/hc/en-us/articles/201898668-Remove-someone-from-a-channel) for details.